# Difficulty using HTML import for javascript dependencies with polymer on Firefox & Safari

Tags: javascript, polymer

I'm building a Polymer application and having difficulty importing javascript dependencies. I've reviewed [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25819898/using-polymer-to-include-jquery-via-html-imports-not-working-in-safari-and-firef), but the solution isn't working for me - the lodash javascript doesn't load via HTML Import. Use of lodash is just an example, the problem exists for any library I try to import this way.

The following test code works fine in chrome, but not in firefox or safari (unless I vulcanize it, which I shouldn't need to do).

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title>Test Page</title>

      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/webcomponentsjs/0.6.0/webcomponents.min.js"></script>

      <link rel="import" href="components/lodash/lodash.html">

      <link rel="import" href="components/test-component/test-component.html">
    </head>
    <body fullbleed unresolved>
      <script>
        window.addEventListener('WebComponentsReady', function(e) {
          console.log("Web Components Ready!");

          document.body.appendChild(document.createElement("test-component"));

          console.log("Index:" + _.now());
        });
      </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

NOTE 1: WebComponentsReady fires *after* HTMLImportsLoaded (see [here](http://webcomponents.org/polyfills/html-imports/))
NOTE 2: I've tried webcomponentsjs 0.5.5 too

**test-component.html**

```
<link rel="import" href="../../bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">

<link rel="import" href="../lodash/lodash.html">

<polymer-element name="test-component">
  <template>
    <style>
      :host {
        display: block;
        font-size: 2em;
        color: cornflowerBlue;
      }
    </style>

    <div id='test_elem' on-tap="{{go}}" fit layout horizontal center center-justified>
      Click Me!
    </div>

  </template>

  <script>
    Polymer({
      ready: function() {
        console.log("test-component component ready!");
      },

      go : function(event, detail, sender) {
        console.log("Component:" + _.now());
      }
    });
  </script>
</polymer-element>
```

**lodash.html**

```
<script type="application/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/3.5.0/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

The ordered output from the safari console:

```
Web Components Ready!
test-component component ready!
ReferenceError: Can't find variable: _
```

Reducing the complexity still gives the same problem:

**index.html** (simpler version)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Test Page</title>

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/webcomponentsjs/0.6.0/webcomponents.min.js"></script>

  <link rel="import" href="components/test-component/test-component.html">
</head>
<body fullbleed unresolved>
  <test-component></test-component>
</body>
</html>
```

I can click on the component at any time after page load and the error still occurs - lodash.js is never available to it. I'm sure there's something obvious I'm missing here, but I'm struggling to resolve it.

Comment: Does it work if you include lodash.js in a `script` tag in the head?

Comment: Yes, but my components are intended for re-use in multiple applications - and different components have varying/multiple external js dependencies. The onus on the application developer to remain aware of all those dependencies (including versions) is very high if js dependencies must be declared in the head. Even worse, the component would no longer have an explicit way of declaring its dependencies, since it now must simply rely on the presence of a <script> tag in the head that it has no control over. Any attempt by the component(s) to include it would cause the script to be loaded twice.

Comment: Instead of having an import for the lodash script. Can you not use it in the template directly? Move **<script type="application/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/3.5.0/lodash.min.js"></script>** from the top to directly above **<script></script>**

Comment: Yes it can be imported directly, but then the issue arises that we have multiple components importing the same javascript file - i.e. the browser attempts to import the same javascript file N times, which will break in many cases. The value of the html import is that it de-dupes and guarantees it will only be imported once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `lodash.html`, remove `type="application/javascript"` from

```
<script type="application/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/3.5.0/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

UPDATE

I've filed a bug with webcomponents.js here: https://github.com/webcomponents/webcomponentsjs/issues/273

Comment: Thanks for working this out - very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a ready to use lodash component like this one: https://github.com/Waxolunist/lodash-element